# CDO Daily data to total annual rainfall

Tags: netcdf4, cdo-climate

I am working with IMERG data of daily rainfall. I use the command with a wildcard (since it is 365 data)

```
cdo merge *.nc4  outfile.nc4
```

I get: cdo merge: Processed 365 variables over 365 timesteps [3.48s 431MB].

Now the question is how I can do to calculate the accumulated precipitation in all that year. I've tried yearsum, yearmon, timmean and always get: "Processed 1 variable over 1 timestep [0.34s 165MB]." It only leaves me the average of the first day or the data of the first day.

I can't understand which operator to use, would someone be so kind as to tell me how to add those 365 data so that I keep the annual data?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show the exact commands you tried?  The commands should work - can you also post the results of "cdo showdate in.nc" on the merged file that you are trying to do the yearsum on?

Comment: Thanks Adrian! i see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65072907/calculate-monthly-average-and-annual-sum-of-precipitation-from-netcdf-with-cdo and i can do now!